# Error using findViewById method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm trying to use the `findViewById()` method to to assign an action to a button I created, however it is giving me the error:

`findViewById(int)` in `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` cannot be applied to `(android.widget.Button)`

at the lines:

```
buttonStudentAccess = (Button) findViewById(buttonStudentAccess);
buttonGuestAccess = (Button) findViewById(buttonGuestAccess);
```

My code is as follows:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class UserTypeSelection extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonStudentAccess;
private Button buttonGuestAccess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_type_selection);

    buttonStudentAccess = (Button) findViewById(buttonStudentAccess);
    buttonGuestAccess = (Button) findViewById(buttonGuestAccess);

    buttonStudentAccess.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonGuestAccess.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonStudentAccess) {
}
    if (view == buttonGuestAccess) {
        //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

The corresponding xml file contains the buttons

```
<Button
    android:text="Guest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonStudentAccess"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonStudentAccess"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonStudentAccess"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonGuestAccess"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonStudentAccess"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonStudentAccess" />

<Button
    android:text="Student"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonStudentAccess"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I used the same syntax to create and assign actions to buttons in my login and registration classes and it didn't create this error. Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: You need to specify where you're getting the id. so here's how you can find the view: `buttonStudentAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStudentAccess);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify where you're getting the id "buttonStudentAccess" from. so here's how you can find the view:

```
buttonStudentAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStudentAccess);
```

To specify that the button or any other view is located in the "resources" package you refer to it as `R` and `.id` specifies that you want to grab the view using its id.

Comment: Hi, the button exists in my resources package in the path \MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_user_type_selection.xml

Comment: Exactly, that's why you need to pass `R.id.buttonStudentAccess` to `findViewById` method, rather than only passing `buttonStudentAccess`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice my mistake, I forgot to pass the methods, it's found the buttons now.

Comment: Yeah, make sure to specify the type of views (`id`, `drawable`, `color`, ...) and that you're getting them from resources, `R`

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonStudentAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStudentAccess);
buttonGuestAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGuestAccess);
```